# Azure DevOps API: can't deserialize body value

Tags: powershell, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to add retention to build run through the API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/leases/add?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) with PowerShell.

My code below shows 3 of my attempts to add retention to the build:

```
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $User, $Token))) #Encrypt token
$Head = @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$myorg/$myproject/_apis/build/retention/leases?api-version=6.0-preview.1"
    
$BodyJson = '{
    "daysValid":"5",
    "DefinitionID":"12706",
    "ownerId":"dashboard",
    "protectPipeline":"true",
    "runId":"2971238"
}'

$BodyConvertTo = @{
    daysValid = "5"
    DefinitionID= "12706"
    ownerId = "dashboard"
    protectPipeline = "true"
    runId = "2971238"
} | ConvertTo-Json

$BodyObj = @{
    daysValid = "5"
    DefinitionID= "12706"
    ownerId = "dashboard"
    protectPipeline = "true"
    runId = "2971238"
}

#BodyJson
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method POST -Headers $Head -Body $BodyJson -ContentType "application/json" -verbose

#BodyConvertTo
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method POST -Headers $Head -Body $BodyConvertTo -ContentType "application/json" -verbose

#BodyObj
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method POST -Headers $Head -Body $BodyObj -ContentType "application/json" -verbose
```

Outcomes:

$BodyJson:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"This request expects an object in the request body, but the supplied data could not be 
deserialized.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.RequestContentException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.WebApi","typeKey":"RequestContentException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
```

$BodyConvertTo:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"This request expects an object in the request body, but the supplied data could not be 
deserialized.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.RequestContentException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.WebApi","typeKey":"RequestContentException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
```

$BodyObj:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred. Activity Id: 5b090138-3392-4d76-8ebb-99d9968959c9.","typeName":"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException, 
Newtonsoft.Json","typeKey":"JsonReaderException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}
```

So I wonder, it don't wants Json nor PSobject, what I should send to body to make it work?

Comment: You are setting all properties as strings by double-quoting them. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/leases/add?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#newretentionlease) it explains that `daysValid`, `definitionId` and `runId` should be **integers**.
`protectPipeline` should be a Boolean: `"protectPipeline":  true` not a string `"protectPipeline":  "true"`. Can you try that?

Comment: Have tried, no luck. Answer below has solution, thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $User, $Token))) #Encrypt token
$Head = @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$myorg/$myproject/_apis/build/retention/leases?api-version=6.0-preview.1"
    
$Body = @(
        @{
            "definitionId" = "129"
            "runId" = "2758"
            "ownerId" = "User:32861cf9-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-6f90c41bf1a6"
            "daysValid" = "365000"
            "protectPipeline" = "false"
         }
    
    )

$BodyJson = ConvertTo-Json $Body

#BodyJson
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method POST -Headers $Head -Body $BodyJson -ContentType "application/json" -verbose
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could elaborate on that. Why does the json body need to be an array?

Comment: @Theo The documentation says that the request body newRetentionLease[] needs to be an array. 
Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/leases/add?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#newretentionlease

Answer (score 0):

Using Shell, it can be done as shown below. Here we frame the JSON string using jq utility, we use a retention period of 365 days and protect the pipeline from accidental deletion

```
$ RETENTION_LEASE_JSON_STRING=$(jq -cn --arg days 365 \
   --arg defId <build definition id> \
   --arg owner <org owner id> \
   --arg protect true \
   --arg runIdVal <build id> '[{ daysValid: $days, definitionId: $defId, ownerId: 
   $owner, protectPipeline: $protect, runId: $runIdVal }]')
$ curl -u <username>:<password> -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d $RETENTION_LEASE_JSON_STRING  https://****.azure.com/{org-name}/{project-name}/_apis/build/retention/leases?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```